# Certain library(packages) not working in R -- error

Tags: r

Majority of the library(packages) are working in R for me, except for these 5:

```
library(plm)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘plm’ in runHook(".onLoad", env, package.lib, package):
cannot open file

library(mlogit)
Loading required package: dfidx
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dfidx’ in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):
cannot open file : No such file or directory
Error: package ‘dfidx’ could not be loaded

library(gplots)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gplots’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
DLL ‘gtools’ not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?

library(erer)
Loading required package: lmtest
Loading required package: zoo
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘zoo’ in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):
cannot open file: : No such file or directory
Error: package ‘zoo’ could not be loaded

library(leaps)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘leaps’ in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):
cannot open file : No such file or directory
```

I uninstalled and reinstalled R Studio.  I think something may be wrong with file directory location, as its default is placed somewhere else, when I install the various packages.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these are dependency errors.  When a package is dependent on another, and the other package is not installed, then you get an error.

So, for instance, the second error on loading mlogit. This package is dependent on dfidx, but dfidx is not installed.  So you have to install that first, then try to load mlogit again.

Sometimes you have to follow the chain of dependencies a few levels until everything loads correctly.

To install a missing package, you can run install.packages("<package name>") on the command line for every missing package.